# Pausing Kafka consumer partitions through a farm

Tags: apache-kafka

We are pointing our kafka consumer to farm of partitions for load balancing.

When using a rest controller endpoint to pause the kafka consumer the service only pauses a few partitions and not all of them. We want all the partitions to be paused but are unable to get them all even with repeated calls.  How would you suggest we accomplish this?  Hazelcast?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "point to a farm of partitions"? Consumers read from partitions, not "point at" them.

Answer (score 0):

`consumer.pause()` would only pause the instance  on which it is called, not the entire consumer group.

A load balancer wouldn't be able to target all of your REST endpoints that wrap the consumers since the requests are randomly routed between all instances, so yes, you'd need some sort of external variable. Zookeeper would be a better option unless you already have a Hazelcast system. [Apache Curator](https://curator.apache.org/index.html) is a high-level Zookeeper client that can be used for this. For example, a [shared counter](https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/shared-counter.html) could be set for `0` state of paused, non-zero for non-paused.